# Terminal prompt not working when opening DevContainer (OSX)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, devcontainer

I am trying out the *Remote - Containers* VSCode extension. I get a docker warning and a prompt message if I want to continue but I can't type anything into the terminal. The cursor looks like it's active but nothing happens when I type.

[image]

So far I have tried:

- Using iTerm.app instead of Terminal.app (in VSCode settings)
- Disabled oh-my-zsh terminal plugin
- Quit and start Visual Studio code

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using generating ssh key in the devcontainer and adding it to github.